# Why does Matlab use 1-d for the correlation distance

Tags: matlab, correlation

I want to use the correlation distance in knnsearch in Matlab. I'm wondering why for the correlation, "'correlation' — One minus the sample linear correlation between observations (treated as sequences of values)." is used. With knnsearch I want to find the k nearest neighbors. But isn't a perfect correlation (which would mean the closest match) be the correlation and not 1-correlation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using correlation as a "distance" would not make much sense. Given two vectors `x1` and `x2`, if `x1`equals `x2` you would expect the distance to be `0`.  However, the correlation (coefficient) of a vector with itself is `1`. If you compute `1 - correlation` you do get `0` for equal vectors.

In general, the "closer" the vectors are (smaller distance) the more correlated they are (higher correlation). So `1 - correlation` makes sense as a measure of similarity.

Note, however, that although `1 - correlation` is a measure of similarity it *is not really a [distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics))*, because it does not satisfy the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Metric_space). As a counterexample, consider the following vectors:

```
x1 = [1 9 8 5];
x2 = [0 7 6 9];
x3 = [9 3 2 6];
```

Then

```
>> pdist([x1; x2], 'correlation') + pdist([x2; x3], 'correlation')
ans =
   1.919533190739275
>> pdist([x1; x3], 'correlation')
ans =
   1.967870959140932
```

Comment: Thank you very much! No I got it. So 0 is the perfect match and 2 is a total dismatch in my case. And thanks for noting the thing with the distance. I want to check for similarity.